# How can I interpolate the wind direction data in python3?

Tags: python, interpolation

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
wind_direction = np.array([230,265,300,330,355,10,45,12,350,14,35,70,90])
x = np.linspace(1,10,13)
xnew = np.linspace(1,10,26)
f = interpolate.interp1d(x, wind_direction ,kind="slinear")
wind_direction_new = f(xnew)
print(wind_direction_new)
```

The problem is when the interpolate value between 355 and 10, or 12 and 350 or 350 and 14, the interpolated value isn't right.

Comment: maybe you should use `-5` (`355-360`) instead of `355`. But it will make problem when you will have `-170` (`190`) and `170` - so it may need different function to interpolate it.

Comment: using Google "interpolate wind speed python" I found module `MetPy` and [Wind and Sea Level Pressure Interpolation](https://unidata.github.io/MetPy/latest/examples/gridding/Wind_SLP_Interpolation.html) and maybe this is the method for your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the problem is the circular wraparound in the wind angles look like artificial jumps to the interp1d function.

You can try using [np.unwrap](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unwrap.html) on `wind_direction` to remove the jumps before intepolating.

Another idea: convert `wind_direction` to [complex phasor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phasor) representation by `wind_phasor = np.exp((2j*np.pi/360) * wind_direction)`, then interpolate, and use `np.angle` to convert the interpolated phasors back to angles.